# load data from cache with NSURL doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, caching, nsdata, nsurl

i'm trying to load a photo from my cache directory.

this is the code where i write the photo into a cache folder:

```
+(BOOL)writeAData:(NSData *)imageData atURL:(NSURL *)fileUrl
{
    return [imageData writeToURL:fileUrl atomically:YES];
}
```

this code works fine, but i have problems when i try to load the code from the cache folders:

i use the method initWithContentsOfURL inside a block:

```
     NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.imageUrl];
```

this is the format of url

```
file://localhost/Users/MarcoMignano/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/0E8E54D8-9634-41CF-934B-A7315411F12F/Library/Caches/image_cache/Meyer%20Library.jpg
```

the URL is correct, but when i try to use the method above i get this error:

```
 ..... [__NSCFString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a0c5b0 .....
```

that is the code when i take the url of my model:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    self.photos = [PhotoAlreadyDisplayed getAllPicture];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        if (indexPath) {
            if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show Image"]) {
                if ([segue.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setImageUrl:)]) {
                    NSURL *url = [[self.photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"url"];
                    [segue.destinationViewController performSelector:@selector(setImageUrl:) withObject:url];
                    [segue.destinationViewController setTitle:[self titleForRow:indexPath.row]];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

whats wrong with the URL? how can i fix it? thank you

**i have find the solution:**
when i load the url for the model, i need to initialize the url using fileURLWithPath method:

```
NSURL *url =  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[self.photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"url"]];
```

Now all works fine, thank you so much for yours help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution: when i load the url for the model, i need to initialize the url using fileURLWithPath method:

```
NSURL *url =  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[self.photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"url"]];
```

Now all works fine, thank you so much for yours help

Answer (score 0):

[`[NSData initWithContentsOfURL:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/initWithContentsOfURL%3a) is expecting an `NSURL` as the argument passed in. It looks like you might be passing in a string, rather than an `NSURL`. Is this the case?

**EDIT:** Just humour me - try replacing

```
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.imageUrl];
```

with

```
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imageUrl]];
```

What happens?

---

Though it doesn't look like you're returning successfully from `initWithContentsOfURL:`, but the snippet below may be of use to others:

```
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:TestURL options:0 error:&error];
if(data) {
  NSLog(@"Success");
}
else {
  NSLog(@"Failed: %@", Error);
}
```

Comment: Can you post any code relating to how `imageUrl` is set/changed?

Comment: Also, if you copy-paste your URL into a web browser, do you see the image?

Comment: i have posted the code wen i take the url of the model, if t put the the code for checking :                                              NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.imageUrl options:0 error:&error];
            if (imageData) {
                NSLog(@"succes");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"erore %@",error);
            }
the application will crash before the if

Comment: also, if i try to paste the url in my browser it doesnt work, but maybe because the file is in an unaccessible or protect part ot the memory

Comment: i have also tried this method : if ([self.imageUrl isFileURL]) and it return NO, so the problem is with the url

Comment: What do you mean by 'an unaccessible part of the memory'? I think you need to look more closely at your URL. Otherwise, I'm out of ideas - sorry.

Comment: BTW: if I copy-paste the URL you've posted above into my test project, `[URL isFileURL]` returns `YES`

Comment: Hi Marco - instead of editing your question, it's best to post a new answer. That way it'll be obvious for anybody who finds this in the future.